# Error in installing tum_ardrone drone_stateestimation

Tags: ros

`/opt/ros/indigo# rosrun tum_ardrone drone_stateestimation`

Error:

> [rosrun] Couldn't find executable named drone_stateestimation
>   below /opt/ros/indigo/tum_ardrone

http://wiki.ros.org/tum_ardrone, I have followed these instructions, but I cant run `drone_stateestimation`. So that I checked **tum_ardrone** folder, but could not find any `drone_stateestimation`. I installed catkin also.

Do I need to do something else?

Comment: I updated my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51118143/3702377)

Answer (score 0):

It's a rosmake Problem probably.Purge Everything u did base On [Wiki_Ros](http://wiki.ros.org/tum_ardrone) It's Outdated and Do A fresh Install Using [Their Github](https://github.com/tum-vision/tum_ardrone) Instruction With Catkin

for `ardrone_autonomy` :
`sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-ardrone-autonomy`

Answer (score 0):

You should clone this package on your **catkin workspace** (`~/catkin_ws/src`) not in `/opt/ros/indigo`.

Then make and build this package with `$ catkin_make` in `~/catkin_ws` directory and pass its dependencies.

Then doing the following lines:

- `$ rospack find tum_ardrone`
- If found above package then:

  - `$ rosrun tum_ardrone drone_stateestimation`

---

[**NOTE**]:

Don't forget *ROSMASTER* `roscore`

---

[**UPDATE**]

In their [github](https://github.com/tum-vision/tum_ardrone) readme:

> **Installation**
>
> ```
> cd catkin_ws/src
> git clone https://github.com/tum-vision/tum_ardrone.git -b hydro-devel
> cd ..
> rosdep install tum_ardrone
> catkin_make
> ```
>
> **Quick start**
>
> ```
> roslaunch tum_ardrone ardrone_driver.launch
> roslaunch tum_ardrone tum_ardrone.launch
> ```